# Getting following File Not Valid Error when launching TestNG.xml file from Jenkins

Tags: xml, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I setup Jenkins to launch my Selenium/TestNG tests. The Jenkins builds succeeds but in the console output is the following error:

> Jenkins Console Output ERROR
>
> There was an error in the forked process
>   Suite file /Users/chrisrhoads/IdeaProjects/SikuliScript_POS/POS_TestConfig.xml is not a valid file
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
>   Suite file /Users/chrisrhoads/IdeaProjects/SikuliScript_POS/POS_TestConfig.xml is not a valid file

The contents of the POM file are below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.POC</groupId>
    <artifactId>SikuliScript_POS</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/POS_TestConfig.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <name>surefire.testng.verbose</name>
                        <value>10</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>





    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

The XML file content is here and to the best of my knowledge it has nothing wrong with it.

```
<suite name="POS_TEST_SUITE" >
    <test name="POS_GENERATE_SALES" >
        <classes>
            <class name="pos_tests.userPlacesEatInOrderTest" />
            <methods>
                <include name="userOpensRibTest" />
                <include name="posOrderTest" />
            </methods>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The project is structured with the TestNG.xml config file in the base directory called POS_TestConfig.xml

[image]

Comment: If you remove all the duplicate and redundant dependencies from your pom.xml and try again, what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the file extension of your suite xml file.

As per the screenshot that you shared, it looks like your suite file name is `POS_TestConfig` but you are referring to it as `POS_TestConfig.xml`.

Please rename the file in your file system to include the `.xml` extension and try again. After that it should work for you.

Comment: You are 100% correct. Epic Facepalm momnent. Thank you so much!