# Tests are not running in maven java

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

[image: Package Explorer]Today i got an new issue in maven, it is telling that **no test to run and telling to refer the dump files**. i can't get the issues.

Down i have attached the both error and pom file

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Tipreports 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Tipreports ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\rck\git\repository\Tipreports\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ Tipreports ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Tipreports ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\rck\git\repository\Tipreports\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Tipreports ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ Tipreports ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.753 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-26T17:39:35+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project Tipreports: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\rck\git\repository\Tipreports\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file C:\testng.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file C:\testng.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:656)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

In Pom i have added all the dependencies. See Below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Tipreports</groupId>
  <artifactId>Tipreports</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
<suiteXmlFile>/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</properties>

  <dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>

    <configuration>

    <suiteXmlFiles>
<suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Why the error is coming i can't understand.i have added all the things correctly but why am getting new sort of error, please sort me out this guys!

Comment: Suite file C:\testng.xml is not a valid file ... seems there 's something wrong with that file.

Comment: @Stultuske i have converted my java testng project to maven and added these dependencies. is their any i need to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting following File Not Valid Error when launching TestNG.xml file from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601029/getting-following-file-not-valid-error-when-launching-testng-xml-file-from-jenki)

Comment: You can see the above image for package explorer , i have attached now clearly and from that  link i can't get the answer. @Mini-Man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below instead of yours and create source folder with name 'src/main/resources' by right clicking on your project name.

```
           <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

        </suiteXmlFiles>
```

Comment: sorry to say this, how you are saying, am not having that path itself. how i can specify that i mean "src/main/resources/testng.xml" ? see my  image above i attached

Comment: @Dileep Does `<suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>` works at your end?

Comment: complete build tag:
<plugin>

               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

               <version>2.12.4</version>

               <configuration>

                  <suiteXmlFiles>

                     <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

                  </suiteXmlFiles>

               </configuration>

            </plugin>

Comment: @Koushick did try creating new source folder (src/main/resources) and move existing testing.xml file into it?

Comment: Thanks @Dileep now it's Working.